# C# code to format amount value

Tags: c#-2.0

Here I have data in a dataset like below

```
EmpID   Amount

100      890
200      4567.78
300      4578
```

Now I want C# code to format Amount column values like below

```
EmpID    Amount

100      0890.00
200      4567.78
300      4578.00
```

Thanks

Anuradha.J

Answer (score 1):

```
int amount = ????; // vale of the amount column
String.Format("{0:0000.00}", amount);
```

Answer (score 0):

ok: this is it:

ToString("000000.00")

Answer (score 0):

You can use .ToString(format) (if is a decimal or something like this).

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx